# Angular run NG SERVE get a error Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'

Tags: angular

An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module `'@angular/compiler-cli/src/tooling'`

Require stack:

> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\typescript.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\angular-cli-files\models\webpack-configs\index.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
> - C:\ANGULAR_UDEMY\ANGULAR\07_bonus-loginApp\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
> - C:\Users\Jesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\lib\init.js
> - C:\Users\Jesus\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng

Comment: angular tooling is missing. re-install angular and try again

Comment: After updating angular/cli, I had same problems. And a lot effort, while cleaning up and repair did not help. I will check out references of package.json in details now.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow steps ->

delete your node_modules folder manually or rm -r node_modules

clean npm cache -> npm cache clean

Install npm by running npm install.

If doesn't work share me to your package.json file here

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1

```
$ rm -rf node_modules dist
$ npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
$ npm install
```

Approach 2

```
$ npm uninstall angular-cli
$ npm install @angular/cli --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Please run below commands in sequence.

1. Command to uninstall Angualr CLI installed globally.

   ```
    npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
   ```
2. These command will clean your cache forcefully and verify it.

   ```
    npm cache clean --force
    npm cache verify
   ```
3. Install Angular CLI latest version.

   ```
    npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
   ```
4. You can run below command to get npm version.

   ```
    npm -v
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete node_modules directory
2. run npm install

works great!